# Spark 2.0 stream - partitioned windows

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, spark-streaming

I want to know if Spark 2.0 streaming library supports partitioned windows. For example, given the stream, I want to partition it by key (can be one field of tuple) and collect elements to sliding windows on each partition.

Another question is, whether Spark 2.0 supports Event time processing? I could not find it on the documentation. 
Here is my code, and it does not output correct results, therefore I am curious if I did something wrong:

```
val keyedStream = tupleStream.transform(rdd => rdd.keyBy(_._1).groupByKey()   )

val aggregatedStream = keyedStream.flatMap( x => x._2.toList )
                                  .window(Milliseconds(slidingWindowLength),Milliseconds(slidingWindowSlide))
                                   .reduce( (t1 ,t2) => (minMaxTuples(t1,t2)) )
```

Comment: Each batch is just a RDD so you can `transform` Stream and apply partitioning you need. Regarding CEP and similar capabilities it is slightly  subjective. You'll find some discussions on user and dev list but I wouldn't expect to much out-of-the-box considering minibatch model.

Comment: @zero323 thanks for reply. Actually I did the same way you proposed, however I am getting wrong results. Actually windows' firing times are not correct I think.